# How can I access data of an instance of a class by using one of its methods by a derived class?

Tags: c++

I admit that I am as a C++ (and OOP) beginner I am sometimes a bit confused as I think "this should be possible!" but having doubts that it is.

Here's my issue:
I want my code to read data from an xml file that has nested nodes in it. For each node I've created a class that shall store information of this node. Now in order to get data of a child node of a node its corresponding class needs to know some data from its parent node that is stored inside an instance of the corresponding class representing the parent node.
Of course the class for the child node will inherit stuff from the parent node class but how can I get specific data from the instance of the parent node class to the instance of the child node class? Of course I could give my child node class to get the necessary information of its parent node. But somehow I think inheritance should do that for me and why write it twice if information is already in an existing instance? Do I need a wrapper class for that?

Here's the definition of one parent node class:

```
class tXmlDoc
    {
    public:
        tXmlDoc();
        ~tXmlDoc();

        void LoadXmlFile(std::string& file_full_name);
        pugi::xml_node GetRootNode();

        std::string GetFileName();
        std::string GetFilePath();
        std::string GetFullPath(const std::string& file_name, std::string& file_path); //returns string containing the full path directly to the file

        void SetFileName(const std::string& file_name);
        void SetFilePath(const std::string& file_path);

        bool GetFileLoaded();
        int GetErrorCode();

        pugi::xml_parse_result GetXmlResult();

    protected:
        std::string file_path = "";
        std::string file_name = "";

        bool file_loaded = false; //provides information is file was successfully loaded (file correctly loaded: true)

        int error_code = 0; //provides information about occuring errors (no error: 0)

        pugi::xml_parse_result xml_result; //contains information about parsing result

        pugi::xml_node root_node; //contains the root node of the xml document  

        pugi::xml_document xml_doc;
    }
    ;
```

and here one representative of the child node class.

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <charconv> 
#include "../../libs/pugixml-1.11/src/pugixml.hpp"
#include "XmlNodes.h"
#include "tXmlDoc.h"

namespace nXml
{
    class tXmlShape : public tXmlDoc
    {
    public:
        tXmlShape();
        tXmlShape(const int shape_id);
        ~tXmlShape();

        pugi::xml_node GetShapeNode(const int, const pugi::xml_node& root_node);

        int GetShapeId();
        int GetAttributNumber(const pugi::xml_node& root_node);

        std::string GetShapeType(const int shape_id, const pugi::xml_node& root_node);
        std::string GetDescription(const int shape_id, const pugi::xml_node& root_node);

        void LoadData();

    protected:
        pugi::xml_node shape_node;

        int shape_id = 0;
        int n_attr = 0;

        std::string description;
        std::string type;
    }
    ;

}
;
```

So in principle I would like to directly use the data stored in tXmlDoc.root node when calling the member function GetShapeType of tXmlShape.

Comment: although I don't know why you make `tXmlShape` inherit `tXmlDoc`

Comment: you should be able to access `root_node` in `tXmlShape`

Comment: Me neither :D Can you help me a bit here how to access ```root_node```? Let's imagine I have an instance ```tXmlDoc Xml_Document``` and I have stored inside ```Xml_Document.root_node``` the information of ```root1```. How can I pass ```root1``` to ```tXmlShape myShape.LoadData()``` without the need to specify a parameter for the LoadData() method (such as ```LoadData(pugi::xml_node& root_node)```?

Comment: it hard to tell from the example, but `tXmlShape::LoadData()` should be able to access `tXmlDoc::root_node`.