# How to pass instantiated content of a class member to the method of another class instance without using method parameter lists (with minimum example)

Tags: c++, class

This question is closely related to [How can I access data of an instance of a class by using one of its methods by a derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66517380/how-can-i-access-data-of-an-instance-of-a-class-by-using-one-of-its-methods-by-a?noredirect=1#comment117592257_66517380) I was apparantly not able to formulate my question clear enough to be understood. So I try again (maybe close the other thread?).

I try to describe what I want to achieve.

I create an instance `myRoot` of a class (let's call it `root_class`) representing the root node of my xml file. This class will have a member `root_node` and I will store the data of the xml root into this member variable. Now I have the specific data of the entire root note contained in `myRoot`.

Now I also create an instance `aChildNode` of a class (e. g. `child_class`) representing a child node of this root node. In order to put data from the xml file into the instance `aChildNode` by a method `LoadData()` of this child_class I need to pass the node data stored inside `myRoot` to the method `LoadData()`. Of course I could use a parameter for `LoadData()` but would prefer to avoid that.

Is there a way to do that?

(To see code please check the link above)

Here is the minimum code. I hope this makes clear what I try to attempt (sorry for being so noobish):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include pugixml module

class root_node
{
public:
    root_node() {};
    ~root_node() {};

    std::string GetRoot()
    {
        //use pugixml to load root node into root
        return root;
    }
    ;

    void LoadData()
    {
        //load data of root (here:fill other_root_data). Will use data stored in std::string root;
    }

protected:
    std::string root; //this member variable is a substitute to pugi::xml_node member root that will take the information of the corresponding root node
    int other_root_data;
};

class child_node
{
public:
    child_node() {};
    ~child_node() {};

    std::string GetChild()
    {
        //use pugixml to load child node into child
        return child;
    };

    void LoadData()
    {
        //load data of child (here:fill other_child_data). Needs to know content of std::string root
    }
    ;

protected:
    std::string child; //this member variable is a substitute to pugi::xml_node member variable child that will take the information of the corresponding child node
    int other_child_data;

};

int main()
{

    root_node myRoot;
    std::string thisroot = myRoot.GetRoot();
    myRoot.LoadData();

    child_node aChildNode;

    std::string thischild = aChildNode.GetChild();
    aChildNode.LoadData(); //<--- here this method needs to know content of thisroot

 
}
```

EDIT: I think I found an answer: [c++: how to pass a variable's value from one class to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991140/c-how-to-pass-a-variables-value-from-one-class-to-another)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve.  The description above is open to many interpretations.

Comment: I will do. May take some minutes.